# Apple Remote for Mid 2011 iMac 27"

Tags: remote, osx-yosemite, infrared

Can the Apple TV remote A1294 or the Apple Infrared Remote A1156 control the sound volume on an iMac Mid-2011 27" while watching an in-browser video (e.g. YouTube/Netflix) or does it work only with iTunes? Does the remote have the ability to control the system volume?

Answer (score 0):

All iMacs made after the G5 iSight and before the 2012 do support the Apple Remote. I've used one with my 2009 MacBook Pro and I can definitely say that the Remote can control the system volume, but I'm not sure about controlling YouTube or Netflix.